# Change value in the list

Tags: .net, powershell

Why i can't change object value in the list?

```
$pt = [Drawing.Point]::Empty
$pt.X = 777
$pt.X # Output: 777

$list = [Collections.Generic.List[Drawing.Point]]::new()
$list.Add([Drawing.Point]::Empty)
$list[0].X = 777
$list[0].X # Output: 0 (Expected 777)

$aList = [Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$aList.Add([Drawing.Point]::Empty)|Out-Null
$aList[0].X = 777
$aList[0].X # Output: 777
```

How I can change value in generic list?

UPD:

I have this code, that returns me a List of "Items". How should I edit this code to use the `Offset()` method as it should be?

```
Add-Type -Ref 'System.Drawing' '
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyClass {
    public struct Item {
        public string Name;
        public Point Location;
    }

    public static List<Item> result = new List<Item> { };

    public static List<Item> foo() {
        result.Add(new Item
        {
            Name = "One",
            Location = new Point(12, 15),
        });
        result.Add(new Item
        {
            Name = "Two",
            Location = new Point(17, 22),
        });

        if(result[0].Location.X == 12){Console.WriteLine("ok");}

        return result;
    }
}'

$items = [MyClass]::foo()
$items[0].Location.Offset(5, 55)
$items[0].Location
```

Or, if I understood **mklement0** correctly, there are no ways to work with the Point object and its methods, if it stored in a collection/array?

---

*In 2022, there are such difficulties with just storing an object in a collection...*

Comment: Seems to be an issue with member access only, because this works as expected: `$list = [Collections.Generic.List[int]]::new(); $list.Add(0); $list[0] = 42; $list[0]`

Comment: `$list = [Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()`

Comment: Cumbersome workaround: `$list[0] = [Drawing.Point]::new( 777, $list[0].Y )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're seeing a **limitation in PowerShell**:

- **In-place updating of .NET *value types* accessed either (a) as a type's *property or field* or (b) by *index* of a *strongly typed collection* isn't supported**.

  - `[Drawing.Point].IsValueType` indicates that the type at hand is a value type.
- Unfortunately, the non-support is *silent*: a *temporary, transient copy* of the property/field value or collection element is modified, leaving the original unmodified, which is what you saw.

  - While noting this limitation isn't part of the documentation per se, it is mentioned *indirectly* in [this Wiki entry](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/wiki/Variables-can-be-assigned-values-as-part-of-an-expression-(with-limitations)#limitations); a more direct discussion is in [GitHub docs issue #5833](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/5833).
  - As for the *technical reason* for this limitation, see [this comment in GitHub issue #12411](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12411#issuecomment-619065783); in short: accessing a value-type instance in PowerShell invariably means operating on a *copy* of it.

**A mitigating factor is that *mutable* .NET value types are *rare*** and, in fact, **even [*officially recommended against*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/struct)**, and that PowerShell constructs `[object[]]` arrays by default, in which value-type instances are *boxed*, i.e. wrapped in a helper `[object]` instance that is itself a .NET *reference type* and therefore avoids the problem.

Thus, the **workaround for *collections***: use an **`[object]`-typed/-storing collection** rather than a strongly typed one:

- Use a PowerShell array constructed with `,`
- Use [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList), which stores its elements as `[object]` instances (which, as your code shows, also avoids the problem.
- As [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) notes, `[object]`-typing your generic list (`[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()`) is an effective workaround too.

The following sample code shows what does and doesn't work:

```bash
# These do NOT work as expected, due to being strongly typed, and the
# type being a mutable *value type*.
[Drawing.Point[]] @([Drawing.Point]::Empty),
[Collections.Generic.List[Drawing.Point]] @([Drawing.Point]::Empty),
# These DO work as expected, thanks to boxing.
[object[]] @([Drawing.Point]::Empty),  # Note: @(...) implicitly creates [object[]]
[Collections.ArrayList] @([Drawing.Point]::Empty),
[Collections.Generic.List[object]] @([Drawing.Point]::Empty) |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_[0].X = 42  # Try to update the 1st element in place.
    $_[0].X       # Output the potentially updated value.
  }
```

Output:

```bash
0     # !! Assignment was in effect ignored.
0     # !! "
42
42
42
```

The **workaround** for types that expose **mutable value types as *properties or fields*** as well as if working with a strongly typed collection can't be avoided:

As implied by [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42)'s comment, the workaround is to **obtain a *copy* of the element or property / field value, modify it, and then replace the original element or property / field value with the modified copy**; using a strongly typed collection as an example:

```bash
# Create a strongly typed collection with a mutable value type.
$arr = [Drawing.Point[]] @([Drawing.Point]::Empty)

# Get a copy of the element, modify it, replace the original
# element with the copy.
$element0Copy = $arr[0]; $element0Copy.X = 42; $arr[0] = $element0Copy

$arr[0].X  # -> 42
```

The same goes for self-mutating *methods* such as `.Offset()`:

```bash
$arr = [Drawing.Point[]] @([Drawing.Point]::Empty)

# Get a copy of the element, modify it, replace the original
# element with the copy.
$element0Copy = $arr[0]; $element0Copy.Offset(42, 43); $arr[0] = $element0Copy

$arr[0]  # -> X = 42, Y = 43
```

---

Your updated example requires *two* workarounds, due to combining a value-type collection element (in a strongly typed `[Item]` list) with a value type that exposes a different value type (a `[System.Drawing.Point]` instance) as a *field*:

```bash
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies System.Drawing '
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyClass {
    public struct Item {
        public string Name;
        public Point Location;
    }

    public static List<Item> result = new List<Item> { };

    public static List<Item> foo() {
        result.Add(new Item
        {
            Name = "One",
            Location = new Point(12, 15),
        });
        result.Add(new Item
        {
            Name = "Two",
            Location = new Point(17, 22),
        });

        if(result[0].Location.X == 12){Console.WriteLine("ok");}

        return result;
    }
}'

$items = [MyClass]::foo()

# Get a copy of the [Item] element at index 0
$itemCopy = $items[0]

# Get a copy of the Location field value (of type [Point])...
$locationCopy = $itemCopy.Location
# ... and update it in place.
$locationCopy.Offset(5 ,55)

# Assign the modified [Point] back to the Location field.
$itemCopy.Location = $locationCopy

# Replace the first element with the modified [Item] copy.
$items[0] = $itemCopy

$items[0].Location # -> X = 17, Y = 70
```

Comment: so there is no way to use methods of Point class? I'v updated my question.

Comment: @Lexxy, the same workaround as for _properties_ applies to self-mutating _methods_ such as `.Offset()` - please see my update.

Comment: @Lexxy, looking at your updated example: I didn't tell the full story: exposing a mutable value-type instances as a type's _property or field_ is subject to the same limitation as in strongly typed collections; please see my update, both the explanation at the top, and the workaround for your updated example at the bottom.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]` over `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`?

Comment: @zett42, `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]` has the advantage that its `.Add()` method has no return value, which is a common pitfall with `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`. Conversely, `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` doesn't have its own `.Where()` and `.ForEach()` methods, which can be a pitfall with `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`. `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]` has more methods, though `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` has some that the former doesn't.

Comment: @Lexxy, I know the reality of the situation is unsatisfying, which this answer lays out (now hopefully) comprehensively. The behavior is unlikely to change; PowerShell is a very capable language in many ways, but it does have its limitations, and the _silent_ non-support of the scenario at hand is very unfortunate. However, given that _mutable_ value types are rare - and recommended against - in .NET, the good news is that the problem doesn't arise often in practice.